# Surrounding a large box by smaller boxes in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying surround a large box by smaller ones. All using css alone. 
and here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/7nya3/4/ 
There are couple of issues:
There is an empty white block on bottom-left.
last box in second row doesn't align properly.

Any handle to fix it ?

```
<style>
.container {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
}
.small-box, .large-box {
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    height:100px;
//-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    border:1px solid white;
    background-color:green;
}

.large-box {
    width:200px;
    //float:left;
    height:200px;
    background-color:orange;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="small-box">x</div>
    <div class="small-box">x</div>
    <div class="small-box">x</div>
    <div class="small-box">x</div>
    <div class="small-box">x</div>
    <div class="large-box">x</div>
    <div class="small-box">x</div>
    <div class="small-box">x</div>
    <div class="small-box">x</div>
    <div class="small-box">x</div>
    <div class="small-box">x</div>            
    <div class="small-box">x</div>            

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you required to use this exact markup?

Anyway, to fix the alignment, the large box needs to be 202px by 202px to cater for the spacing between the smaller boxes.

Largebox's width = 100px + 2px + 100px = 202px (same goes for the height)

I'd consider using absolute positioning for all boxes, then this is rather easy to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that, when you're floating the boxes, as soon as the large-box is added to the row, the next boxes go to the right or below it.

The solution is to put 2 small boxes in a special vertical container.

```
    <div class="double-box">
        <div class="small-box">x</div>
        <div class="small-box">x</div>
    </div>
```

and CSS:

```
   .double-box{
       width:100px;
       float:left;
       height:200px;  
   }
```

And regarding the alignment, the issue is (as HaukurHaf mentioned) the fact that you did not take into account the margin between the two boxes below/above the large box. So, if you accordingly modify the width for the large-box (`202px`) and for the double-box(`102`) everything should display accordingly.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vnsyL/

-- EDIT --

As suggested in the comments, another alternative that can be used instead of changing the widths to adapt to the margins/borders is to use the [`box-sizing`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) css property with the `border-box` value:

```
.small-box, .large-box, .double-box {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: yeah this is nice but there is still small border overlap between large box and double box. and boxes in right column don't seem to align.. And how would this if boxes are to be added dynamically ? just compute height/width and decide ?

Comment: I've just updated it to take margins into account. Check the fiddle. :)

Comment: In case you want to add the boxes dynamically, you would have to use _javascript_ to make sure the width of the large box covers the borders/margins of small boxes above/below. Another solution would be to add the width inline, if you are generating the page server-side: `<div class="large-box" style="width: 202px">`, where the `202` value would be dynamically computed on the server.

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Thdkg/) just used -moz-box-sizing property instead of making width 202. thanks

Comment: Great! Just make sure you also add the version compatible with other browsers as well [`box-sizing`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)

Comment: I've also adapted the response for future readers including your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Cosmin SD is correct, but you did miss off a small box so adding that causes it to go below, so add another class to the new box and then position it using `margin-top` into place and then increase the large box width and height to align the right and bottom small boxes.

http://jsfiddle.net/7nya3/5/

Comment: Nice solution. An issue (actually more of a complication) appears though if the size of the larger box grows to more than 2 small boxes or there are more layers of small boxes surrounding the large one.

Comment: the size of the large box also needs to take into account the width of the border added to the small boxes, the larger the border the more you need to increase the size of the larger box. The small box is width and height 100px plus 1px border making it 102px from end to end. You need to add missing border space to the large box, by either adding a 1px border to the large box or in this case, just increase the width and height by 2px, 1px top and bottom and 1px left and right sides.

Answer (score 1):

Fixing this without some client-side scripting won't be easy — if not near impossible.  When considering the float order and pattern of objects, there's a natural way that things fall into place. Forgive me if I don't communicate this eloquently enough, but please see this reference:

[image]

A:  at point A I've extended the yellow block to show it extended beyond the length of its neighboring green block.

B:  at point B, you see where the block to the right ends.  The natural float placement is to begin immediately to the next line and as far left as it can go before colliding with another float (in this case the yellow block).  So in this example, row three begins to the right of the yellow box.  It will *never* naturally skip all the way over to the left side of the set of blocks because the yellow block is "in the way".

C:  at point C we see where that third row of blocks ends in regard to their floats. Because there are no blocks extending below the point C.  Items in row three will never start left of items that extend down and "collide" with floating items.

D:  at point D we have the last row starting physically on the next line after the third row terminates.  Row four will never start up in that empty white space.

I realize this doesn't solve your problem, but at least helps (in part) explain the behavior of floats.  You will likely need to integrate some jQuery or other client-side processing to handle the placement of objects.  I do believe there are some libraries out there that will handle the kind of float behavior you want (like some of the photo-style blogging you'd see on Tumblr and other similar sites).